# Ipad stream m3U8 losing image after few moments on iOS 6

Tags: image, ipad, video, stream, ios6

I have a problem with few `m38u` streams that I play on my I pad
The code is this:

```
<video width="440" height="280" controls="controls"
 src="http://fms3.mediadirect.ro/live3/protvint/playlist.m3u8?publisher=1"
type="video/mp4" >
</video>
```

The problem is that after few seconds(10-15), the stream is losing image/gets behind/ repeats itself and then at some point is coming back.I noticed this on other streams identically behavior.

I had iOS 5.1, and they worked flawlessly, but after i upgraded to iOS 6, this problem started to manifest!

Is anyone else knows about this problem? is a iOS6 bug or something I'm missing?
Please help!